# Does SSH generate traffic when listening?

Tags: android, ssh, firmware

Does a service, for example, SSH, generate traffic when only listening (e.g. does it advertise itself in some way) when there is no connection established?

I ask as on Android devices for example, we can monitor incoming and outgoing traffic, great - we can block specific requests, IPs, app permissions etc. but even when doing this, could there be a service listening in the background (hidden in the firmware) such that the device can be accessed? Then all the monitoring/blocking would not be an effective defense, if the service generates no traffic (or even very little such that it is not noticed).

Answer (score 1):

## Does an open port generate traffic

No, only a connected port generates traffic. An open port is just one that will respond if you talk to it.

## Is it possible to detect open ports locally

On Linux, the command `netstat -tupln` will show the listening ports, and the associated processes.

## Is it possible to detect open ports remotely

If the port is TCP, and open to anyone then you can detect it by checking for the 3 way handshake.

If it uses UDP, it is only checkable if it responds, either with a port unreachable message, or data. If the traffic is just dropped you cannot tell if this was because ICMP is blocked, or if your message just didn't get a reply.

Comment: Thanks - does this imply that if I look for programs listening on a given port, without root (sudo), then a program could be running (under root) and listening without my knowledge?

Comment: You can see that something is listening, but you won't be able to tell what